# What properties must fulfill a semiring S so that every automorphism thereof be able to be extended to a canonical field of fractions automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

Suppose $S$ is an infinite semi-ring with zero element and unity. Let $A_S$ be the ring obtained from $S$ by adjoining to it the additive inverses and $K_{A_S}$ the field of fractions of this ring.

Can any semi-ring automorphism of $S$ be canonically extended to a field automorphism of $K_{A_S}$? Or must additional properties be fulfilled by $S$ and if yes, which?

Comment: You mean $A_S$ is an integral domain ? It is easy to see any automorphism of $A_S$ extends to $Frac(A_S)$ with $\phi(a/b) = \phi(a)/\phi(b)$, well-defined since $\phi(b) = 0$ iff $b=0$. For extending an automorphism of $S$ to $A_S$ it is the same : $\phi(-c) = - \phi(c)$, $a-b= c$ implies $a=b+c$,$ \phi(a) = \phi(b)+\phi(c)$, $\phi(a-b)=\phi(c) = \phi(a)-\phi(b)$

Comment: For us Frenchmen, "integral domain" is "anneau intègre" right? If yes I indeed require no divisor of zero, sorry not to have said it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, by the way. Don't hesitate to turn it into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Why not write it yourself ? Assuming $A_S$ is unital commutative but with a few zero-divisors leads to a more interesting problem.

Comment: It wouldn't be really honest but if you really feel reluctant to answer, I'll do it.